# Failsafe doesn't execute correctly

Tags: python

I'm making a scientific notation writing program, so let me show you the code:

```
import time

def scientific_notation(number):
    decimal = ""
    for thing in str(number):
        """
        Loops through the number to add stuff to "decimal"
        (probably not necessary but i'm going to keep it 
        there in case I need a filter.)
        """
        if len(decimal) == len(str(number)):
            break
        else:
            decimal += thing
    decimal = decimal.replace('0','')
    print(decimal)
    while float(decimal) > 10:
        # Uses decimal notation
        actual = ''
        # To keep track of the original place
        for x in range(0,len(str(number))):
            actual += str(number)[x]
            decimal = decimal.replace(str(number)[x],str(number)[x]+'.')
            # Adding decimal points to each place until the float version of that is less than 10
            if decimal.count('.') > 1:
                # if there's more than one decimal, replace that value with what it was before
                decimal = decimal.replace(str(number)[x],actual)
            elif float(decimal) > 10:
                # if the float version of the decimal is more than 10, wait for the while loop to realize that by doing nothing
                pass
            else:
                pass
    else:
        # Output
        power = '10^'+str(str(number).count('0'))
        print(decimal+" * "+power)


scientific_notation(102)
```

Alright, now that you've looked at it let me tell you what's going on.

So, in the while loop, my if statement isn't executing

```
if decimal.count('.') > 1
```

or at least, not executing correctly and that's causing a

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.102.'
```

because my while loop tries to convert it to a float, but gets '1.102.' and raises a ValueError because you can't convert something with two decimal points into a float. Any ideas on why the if statement isn't working? I dunno, maybe i'm just being stupid.

Comment: Stack Overflow's [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are currently only for web-related (HTML/CSS/JS) questions. If you enter python code into them they do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @stybl sorry about that, how should I format python code?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help center page, which explains how formatting on SO works. While you're at it, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already, and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @stybl nvm it looks like Wondercricket already formatted it correctly, thanks!

Comment: What happens with `if list(decimal).count('.') > 1:`? I can't test right now.

Comment: @roganjosh the same ValueError

Comment: What is the output of `list(decimal)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eek your code is scary, and does some unintended things right off the bat. For instance:

```
decimal = ""
for thing in str(number):
    """
    Loops through the number to add stuff to "decimal"
    (probably not necessary but i'm going to keep it 
    there in case I need a filter.)
    """
    if len(decimal) == len(str(number)):
        break
    else:
        decimal += thing
```

That is the same as

```
decimal = str(number)
```

also

```
decimal = decimal.replace('0','')
```

That turns `102` into `12` which can't be intentional.

---

Let's look at a different algorithm, and handle this with arithmetic instead of string manipulation.

```
def scientific_notation(number):
    n = 0
    while number > 10:
        n += 1
        number /= 10
    print(f"{number} * 10^{n}")

>>> scientific_notation(102)
1.02 * 10^2
```

Comment: Separately, I think it's worth noting that anytime you start to write `for i in range(len(some_variable)): some_variable[i]`, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. Python has an `enumerate` builtin that very happily lets you iterate over the elements while still tracking indices. `for i, ch in enumerate(some_variable)` is much preferred.

Comment: This idiom has become so ordinary to me that I have a couple of times caught myself writing `for i, _ in enumerate(something)` when all I cared about was the index.